# Does this limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{[x]}{x}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{[x]}{x}$ if it exists. Here $[x]$ means the integer part of $x.$

The solution says that the limit does not exist. I am trying to prove this claim by computing the left hand and right-hand limit. Thus,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{[x+h]}{x+h}=?$$

What do I after this step?

Comment: What you are doing is attempting to find the derivative of $x \mapsto \frac{[x]}{x}$ at zero.  This is distinct from finding the limit of $\frac{[x]}{x}$ at zero.

Comment: You are mixing things. You first ask about the limit of $f$ at $x=0$, and then try to calculate its derivative. Which one is it? (none exists, though).

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} = +\infty, \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} = 0$, thus it does not exist there.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  If $x \in (0,1)$, then $[x] = 0$.  If $x \in (-1,0)$, then $[x] = -1$.

> We claim that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{[x]}{x}$ does not exist.  To show this, we will use the hint above to show that the left-hand and right-hand limits are not equal.  First, the left-hand limit:
>  $$ \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{[x]}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{-1}{x} = -\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{1}{x} = -(-\infty) = +\infty. $$
>  Observe that this alone is enough to conclude that the limit does not exist, but here we are saying that the limit fails to exist in a specific way.  That is, the right-hand limit is positive and infinite.  On the other hand, the left-hand limit is given by
>  $$ \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{[x]}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{0}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} 0 = 0.$$
>  Note that the left-hand limit is finite, in contrast to the left-hand limit.  Since the left- and right-hand limits do not agree, the function $x\mapsto \frac{[x]}{x}$ itself has no limit at zero (even in the sense of having an infinite limit).

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $-1<x<0$ we have $\frac{[x]}{x}=\frac{-1}{x} > 1$ and for any $0<x<1$ we have $\frac{[x]}{x}=\frac{0}{x}=0$.